# Excel 2007, inconsistent logical OR response

Tags: excel, excel-2007, logical-or

Regarding Excel 2007 (though it may pertain to other versions):
I want to apply Excel Data Validation to manually inputted data. In this particular case, the input is of the form NN.nnnnh, where the digit "h" is a "half-digit". That is, it can either be 0 or 5.
The spread-sheet converts land-surveying that is manually entered in the form of Feet, Inches, and 16ths of an inch, into decimal feet

The function of the **half-digit** is to allow the *optional* higher-precision to 1/32nd of an inch.

**For example:**
43.0913 is the raw entry for 43 feet, nine inches, and 13/16ths of an inch.

Now, by adding the *half-digit* in the fifth decimal place, a precision of 1/32" can be expressed.

**For example:**
27.08135 is the manual entry for 27 feet, 08 inches, and (13.5/16=) 27/32nds of an inch.
The raw input NN.nnnnh is decomposed and converted into feet as a decimal number, using Excel TRUNC function. This manner of conversion is analogous to the more familiar conversion of angles entered as D˚M'S", into DD.dddddd).

I want to assure that the 5th decimal place, manually entered, is ONLY Zero or 5.

I can *separately* apply logical tests to determine if the fifth-decimal entry is Zero, **or** 5.

But, when I combine those separate logical tests using the **=IF(OR(**  structure,  I get inconsistent results *IFF* the manually-entered data has an integer value (i.e., in the NN.nnnnh format, any length of just one foot or greater, manually entered as >= 1.00000). Unless I undertake the surveying of table-top architectural scale models, this has serious limitations !!!

I have attached an example spreadsheet to illustrate the formulae used and the results. **If anybody can shed some light on this, it would be appreciated.**
(If there is a way to simply Attach a *.xlsx example....please let me know. I had intended to do this, and then discovered that it seems to be impossible!)

Comment: Not sure you can attach actual workbooks here. Perhaps simpler to post half a dozen or so varied examples together with expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Use MROUND to test if the number is the same:

```
=A1=MROUND(A1,0.00005)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Well, that works (I have never used the MROUND function in this manner) ! Very clever.

Comment: But, I am still flummoxed by the inconsistent results of combining my separately-useful logical tests using the IF(OR( structure.

Comment: I can't help you with that as I have not seen your formula.

Comment: First Test:              =IF( TRUNC(B3,5)-TRUNC(B3,4)=0, "ok", "error")

Comment: Second Test: =IF( TRUNC(B3,5)-TRUNC(B3,4) = 0.00005, "ok", "error")

Comment: Combined tests: =IF(OR (TRUNC(B3,5)-TRUNC(B3,4)=0,TRUNC(B3,5)-TRUNC(B3,4)=0.00005), "OK", "error")
Try these tests with values 0.00000, 0.00001, 0.00005, 9.00000, 9.00005, 9.00003

Comment: (I am not getting any Excel error-messages with these logical tests, so I must assume that they're internally consistent and so forth....)